# Interface parameter constraints

Tags: c#, interface, constraints

My interface (part of it):

```
public interface IRepository
{
    Task<T> Insert<T>(T item) where T : class, ISyncable;
}
```

My implementation:

```
public class TableStorageRepository: IRepository
{
    public async Task<T> Insert<T>(T item) where T: class, ISyncable
    {
        TableOperation.Insert(item);
    }
}
```

My implementation won't work because `TableOperation.Insert` needs to be an `ITableEntity` as well as an `ISyncable`

I can't update my interface to this: `Task<T> Insert<T>(T item) where T : class, ISyncable, ITableEntity;` because then my other IRepository implementations won't work anymore.

I can't add `ITableEntity` to my implementations parameter constraints either because then the constraints don't match with the interface constraints anymore, which results in the following error:

*"The constraints for parameter type 'T' of method..."*

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Comment: If you can't make a separate interface/method then simply cast, live with a possible runtime error and document it

Comment: I would suggest that you check the type of `item` at runtime in your `TableStorageReposity` and then throw an `ArgumentException` if the passed object does not implement `ITableEntity`...

Comment: Would it be possible to bridge the gap? Hide the implementation detail? Meaning that you would accept any class that implements `ISyncable`, and then handle the difference internally?

Comment: Thanks. Just casting the object and handle the invalid cast exception seems the only way to go for now. The only side effect with this is that the interface doesn't force to use the correct type, so you will only find out at runtime, not compile time. Maybe I should reconsider my interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your set up is just wrong. You are breaking the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Your `IRepository` interface defines a contract. This contract says that it can insert any `T` as long as `T` is `ISyncable` and a reference type.

Your class `TableStorageRepository` *breaks* that contract. It can't handle any `ISyncable`, it can only handle `ITableEntity`. It has no business implementing an interface it can't live up to, so don't do that.

You can get around this with messy runtime type checks and such, but its nothing short of a hack. Your building blocks are bad, so everything you build upon them will be flaky at best.

One valid mitigation strategy when you simply can't avoid being in this spot, is having the interface define a method that tells the consumer if certain operations are valid: `bool CanInsert<T>` but you are saying you can't modify the interface, so this isn't an option.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here, like I said: this would be ideal: Task<T> Insert<T>(T item) where T : class, ISyncable, ITableEntity; But unfortunately I can't add ITableEntity because it will break my other repositories. For TableStorage I still need the ISyncable, but additionally I need the ITableEntity. I could add the CanInsert but I'd rather do without, I never said I couldn't modify the interface. Anyways, thanks for insight/comment/answer!

Comment: @Niels I'm not missing the point. You are attempting to force a class to implement an interface it can't really implement; Not all `ISyncable`s are `ITableEntity`s. This is not a good situation to be in, as you are experiencing, and the type system is fighting against you, not helping you. Sometimes there is no other choice, in those cases, providing the user a way to *know before hand* if the call will succeed is the best you can do to avoid [vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/): `System.IO.Stream` is a classic example with `CanSeek`.

Comment: @Neils My confusion might be believing that `ITableEntity` implements `ISyncable`. If thats not the case then you are in a even worse situation.

Comment: Don't worry, I am not launching a rocket or anything, just experimenting with tableStorage and looking for a simple solution so I can continue for now. My setup is fine, only tableStorage is being "flaky" until now, everything else works fine. Maybe the conclusion will be not to use TableStorage in the end, we'll see.